# Incorrect range height, was 64 but should be 938 using setValues

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am attempting to loop through different latitudes and longitudes of a location and a destination and an arrival time through Google Directions APIs specified in my spreadsheet.

```
function getDeparture() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Houses');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Details');

  var propertyLinks = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var propertyLength = propertyLinks.length;

  var arrival = ss2.getRange("B1").getValues()[0][0];

  var person1 = ss2.getRange("B3").getValues()[0][0];
  var person2 = ss2.getRange("B2").getValues()[0][0];

  var allLat = ss.getRange("I2:I").getValues();
  var allLng = ss.getRange("J2:J").getValues();

  var person1Durations = [];
  var person1Arrivals = [];
  var person1Departs = [];

  var person2Durations = [];
  var person2Arrivals = [];
  var person2Departs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < propertyLength; i++) {
    var isEmpty = propertyLinks[i][0] === "" || allLat[i][0] === ""  || allLng[i][0] === "" ? true : false;
    if (!isEmpty){
      var lat = allLat[i][0];
      var lng = allLng[i][0];

      // person1
      var person1Direction = getDirection(lat, lng, person1, arrival);
      var person1Duration = getDuration(person1Direction);
      var person1Arrival = getArrival(person1Direction, arrival);
      var person1Depart = getDepartTime(person1Direction);

      person1Durations.push([person1Duration]);
      person1Arrivals.push([person1Arrival]);
      person1Departs.push([person1Depart]);

      //person2
      var person2Direction = getDirection(lat, lng, person2, arrival);
      var person2Duration = getDuration(person2Direction);
      var person2Arrival = getArrival(person2Direction, arrival);
      var person2Depart = getDepartTime(person2Direction);

      person2Durations.push([person2Duration]);
      person2Arrivals.push([person2Arrival]);
      person2Departs.push([person2Depart]);
    }
  }

  ss.getRange("B2:B").setValues(person2Durations);
  ss.getRange("C2:C").setValues(person1Durations);
  ss.getRange("D2:D").setValues(person2Departs);
  ss.getRange("E2:E").setValues(person1Departs);
  ss.getRange("F2:F").setValues(person2Arrivals);
  ss.getRange("G2:G").setValues(person1Arrivals);
}

function getDirection(lat, lng, destination, arrival) {
  var address = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat + ", " +  lng + "&destination=" + destination + "&mode=transit&arrival_time=" + arrival;
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(address);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  var routes = json["routes"];
  var legs = routes[0]["legs"];
  return legs;
}

function getDuration(legs) {
  var duration = legs[0]["duration"]["value"];
  var minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
  var seconds = duration % 60;
  var result = Math.ceil(minutes + '.'  + seconds);
  return result;
}

function getArrival(legs, destArrival) {
  var arrival;
  if(legs[0]["arrival_time"] !== undefined){
    arrival = legs[0]["arrival_time"]["text"];
  }else{
    arrival = destArrival;
  }
  return arrival;
}

function getDepartTime(legs, destArrival) {
  var depart;
  if(legs[0]["departure_time"] !== undefined){
    depart = legs[0]["departure_time"]["text"];
  }else{
    depart = destArrival - legs[0]["duration"]["text"];
  }
  return depart;
}
```

As far as I can tell I am returning all the correct values. I am looping through all the locations I have specified in the sheet (64) and dismissing any empty cells in the range specified by

`var propertyLinks = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();`

On the following line:

```
ss.getRange("B2:B").setValues(person2Durations);
```

Is where I am getting the following error

```
Incorrect range height, was 64 but should be 938 (line 55, file "Code")
```

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "B2:B" use "B2:B" + personDurations.length